# Mongodb c# InsertOne() - How to Handle exception

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I am using mongodbc# driver which includes legacy driver. And using *InsertOne()* method insert records. But it is void, how do I know if there is error in insertion and what type of exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It will raise an exception if an error occurs. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/error_handling/#write-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Just use Try Catch

```
try {
db.products.insertOne(
   { "item": "envelopes", "qty": 100, type: "Self-Sealing" },
   { writeConcern: { w : "majority", wtimeout : 100 } }
);
} catch (e) {
   print (e);
}
```

it will catch the Exception.